# Cannot create SQL table with query variable as table name in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, create-table

I am passing a query variable in PHP. I would like to make it the table name, but I know there is probably a SQL syntax error. When I print the statement, the variable is passed meaning it works, but the database simply isn't created.

Here is my code for the creation of the database:

```php
$DBName = "database_name";  
$sql = "CREATE TABLE '$DBName'.'$login' (  
    ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    AgentClients varchar(15),  
    ClientTotal int  
    )";  
mysql_query($sql,$link);
where `$login = $_POST['login'];
```

Also, I'm not worried about security breaches at the moment, so don't worry about that.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing "table" and "database" a lot. Has the database been created before this code? (I'm not even sure if that matters) But you might need to run `CREATE DATABASE '$DBName'` first?

Comment: echo $sql; whats that return?

Comment: Run the printed query in phpMyAdmin or any other mysql client and you will get all the errors.

Comment: table for each login, is not great structure, and i rally hope you are sanitising the post value.

Comment: Replace `'` by ` and add `PRIMARY KEY` after `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: thanks for your help everyone, after adding the primary key and backticks, it's running well. Also @Dagon I am sanitising values and have anti injection code, this was solely for comprehension purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use backticks for your tablename, and not quotes:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$DBName`.`$login` (  
  ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  AgentClients varchar(15),  
  ClientTotal int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`) 
)";
```

Comment: or omit them altogether and use no back ticks.

Comment: He's also using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` without defining a key. That will fail, right?